# Are tail calls on diverging functions optimized in Rust?

Tags: function, rust, calling-convention, tail-call-optimization, tail-call

If I have the following functions:

```rust
fn a() -> ! {
    b()
}

fn b() -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

Does Rust optimize such calls to simple jumps?

I have looked at a [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bfa1a03b8b16962c0614f02e6bad1415) to show the assembly, but `a` seems to just `callq` the `b` function.

Is this always the case?

Comment: As you cna see in the playground output, the assembly was generated without optimisations: `[unoptimized + debuginfo]`

Comment: When compiling the playground example with optimizations, both `a()` and `b()` get inlined into main, and the assembly code simply becomes `.LBB5_1: jmp .LBB5_1`.

Comment: Note that you rarely get guarantees what exactly the optimizer is going to do. I recommend not to care unless you have an actual performance problem.

Comment: Why would you expect this optmization only for tail calls, by the way?

Comment: `.LBB0_1:
 jmp .LBB0_1` => https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=1fd2857df2dcdfe4de41cb911a12e9e7

Comment: @SvenMarnach cause not tail call need stack ?

Comment: @Stargateur A diverging function never returns, regardless of whether it's a tail call or not.

Comment: With the `loop`, optimizations reduce it to `.LBB5_1: jmp .LBB5_1`. But if I redefine `b` to recursively call itself, all the jumps are replaced by `callq`s. Seems like a missed opportunity for optimization - you really should just jump to a diverging function instead of calling it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can tell the compiler to inline a function using [`#[inline]`](https://nnethercote.github.io/perf-book/inlining.html): Technically, this does not *guarantee* inlining, but it should work in reasonable situations. I would recommend using this.

Second, as noted in the comments, you have to do an optimised build to see such inlining. Maybe a better tool for this would be Compiler Explorer. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/dYWEace3c) is a slight modification of your example (notice the `-O` flag in compiler options). As you can see, everything is inlined into one infinite loop, and the compiler can even eliminate some work done in the loop if it can prove that it is useless.

Overall, unless you use `#[inline]`, the result will depend on the contents of `a` and `b`. So I would advise to create some kind of minimal-viable-implementation of what you are trying to achieve with `a` and `b`, and then test it in Compiler Explorer.

Comment: What about mutually-recursive functions such that a calls b and b calls a both in the tail?

Comment: As always, depends on the compiler settings/version/etc... so it's best to check your specific use case. In general, simple cases of mutual recursion are inlined automatically (see https://godbolt.org/z/Pd7en83q1). But this will probably stop working at some level of function complexity. It's hard to tell exactly what that level of complexity is though.